# Cannot add order id column to admin area - Magento Enterprise

Tags: magento

I'm new to Magento. I'm trying to add Order ID next to Order # in Magento Admin.
I copied

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
```

to

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
```

and added following codes in

### protected function _prepareColumns()

```
$this->addColumn('entity_id',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('ID'),
            'width' => '50px',
            'type'  => 'number',
            'index' => 'entity_id',
    ));
```

but it is not showing any difference in the admin / sales / order page.

I followed many tutorials. None is working for me.

I'm using Magento Enterprise v1.14.2.0

Can you please tell me what wrong I'm doing?

Regards,

-Naveed

Comment: Edit web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php ` protected static $_showTemplateHints=1;
    protected static $_showTemplateHintsBlocks=1;`  Is the block 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid' displayed?

Comment: your comments helped me fix the issue. thank you very much @juporag